# Como tener varios Outputs dependiendo la configuracion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, libreria

Tengo un proyecto el cual es una libreria .dll y la forma que hice para debugearlo es crear un Form que utiliza las funciones del dll.

Si yo quiero compilar el "Modo debug" lo que hago es ir a propiedades del Proyecto y cambiar el Tipo de salida "**Biblioteca de clases**" por "**Aplicacion de Windows**" y correrlo en debugmode
hasta aca todo bien pero esto resulta tedioso si quiero compilar el .dll y si algo falla cambiar a la aplicacion windows.

Visual Studio tiene una opcion de cambiar la configuracion dependiendo un perfil como se puede configurar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una "solución" puede tener varios proyectos. En una misma solución agregas tu proyecto dll y otro proyecto de prueba al cual le agregas por referencia el otro proyecto (el de la dll) para esto en el explorador de soluciones buscas "Dependencias" haces click derecho y "Agregar referencias del proyecto". Cuando haces un cambio en la dll automáticamente se ve reflejado en el proyecto de pruebas y cuando debugueas el proyecto de pruebas también se debuguea la dll

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar con esto de las dependencias muchas gracias